# Use JavaScript to find a spesific line, and extract a number in this line?

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, line, extract

I have this pice of HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="modaction('warn', '978532')">Warn</a>
```

How can I use JavaScript to search for *modaction('warn'* to find this spesific line, and then extract the number, which in this case is *978532*? The number will always be different.

Any explanation or links to content on this would be greatly appreciated. I am still learning JavaScript, so you could call me a complete newcomer. Please excuse me if I am creating a double question!

Comment: What about that : `grep modaction | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` ? :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution :

```js
html = document.body.innerHTML;
n = html.match(/modaction\('warn', '(\d+)'\)/)[1];
console.log(n);
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="modaction('warn', '978532')">Warn</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **class** or **ID** to that anchor tag or use anything to get the anchor tags object in javascript.

Then you can use getAttribute('onclick') to get "modaction('warn', '978***)"

Example

```
<a href="operators/combination/combineall.html" onclick="modaction('warn', '123123123')" 
class="something">warn/a>

document.querySelector('.something').getAttribute('onclick') //modaction('warn', '12312313')
```

It would be now easier to fetch the number using string **split** or **substring**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select the element with `id` and then read the value of `onclick` attribute. See the following example.

Assuming your anchor has id "your_anchor" then:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("your_anchor").getAttribute("onclick");
```

You can now use the value of x to extract the number by string manipulation